# Keep getting "Exchange Web Services are not currently available for this request because" error?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, exchangewebservices

We have an application that logs in as an exchange user and does simple tasks like delete / saves / sends emails etc. I'm seeing a lot of two errors in our Splunk report:

**"Exchange Web Services are not currently available for this request because none of the Client Access Servers in the destination site could process the request"**

and

**"Problem deleting email [ item id: (item ID string) ] - The specified object was not found in the store., The process failed to get the correct properties."**

I've read that it's important to include:
**service.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", MailboxToAccess);**
when impersonating users and that that may be the issue, but what about when you are just logging in as a user?

Here's the code where we set up the exchange service:

```
    public ExchangeServiceClient(ILog logger, IContentTypeHelper contentTypeHelper)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _contentTypeHelper = contentTypeHelper;

        if (EvidenceSettings.Default.AppEmailUserName.Equals("Windows Credentials", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            _exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
            _exchangeService.Url = new Uri(PartnerEvidenceSettings.Default.ExchangeServiceAddress);
        }
        else
        {
            _exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
            _exchangeService.Url = new Uri(EvidenceSettings.Default.ExchangeServiceAddress);
            _exchangeService.Credentials = new WebCredentials(EvidenceSettings.Default.AppEmailUserName, EvidenceSettings.Default.AppEmailPassword);
            _exchangeService.TraceEnabled = true;
            _exchangeService.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        }
    }
```

And here's an example of when we use the service (just a single example, but all pretty similar functions):

```
    public void DeleteMailMessage(string identifier)
    {
        // If this email was an attachment in another email, then only delete the container email
        if (identifier != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var ids = new[] { new ItemId(identifier) };
                var responseCollection = _exchangeService.DeleteItems(ids, DeleteMode.MoveToDeletedItems, null, null);
                foreach (var response in responseCollection)
                {
                    if (response.Result == ServiceResult.Error)
                    {
                        _logger.Error($"Problem deleting email [ item id: {identifier} ] - {response.ErrorMessage}");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error($"Error deleting email [ item id: {identifier} ]", ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

My question is, do we need to be including the HTTPHEADERS, or is something else causing this issue? If it's not that, I'm not quite sure what could be causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

Those two error are different and generally not related

> "Exchange Web Services are not currently available for this request because none of the Client Access Servers in the destination site could process the request"

Generally this is a routing error so yes you should always included the X-AnchorMailbox header no matter if its impersonation or not. (Eg if you look at any Microsoft Mail client Outlook,OWA, Outlook Mobile you will always see these headers).

> "Problem deleting email [ item id: (item ID string) ] - The specified object was not found in the store., The process failed to get the correct properties."

This is usually an Item error or permissions error eg no access to the Mailbox itself or your trying to access something like the Audit folder in the mailbox etc. It can also mean the Item in question has moved in the Mailbox.